# Cant get any ETH for testing from any Test Network

Tags: solidity, ether

I have tried my hands on every Test Network for getting ETH but to no avail. Can someone please suggest where can I get ETH for testing my smart contract. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest this faucet for Kovan: https://ethdrop.dev/

*Note: Am not affiliate with that link, Im just an user.